# Changing Behaviour of Perl's FindBin

Tags: perl, module

I've got a collection of Perl scripts which use the FindBin module. There are some data files which the scripts use, and are expecting to find them in `$FindBin::Bin/../share/somedir/`. I'm customizing the installation so those files now exist is `/some/other/share/dir/`. Is there any way to customize the behaviour of FindBin with something like, say, an environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can solve this problem with `FindBin` module, because it's designed to solve particular problem: *locate directory of original perl script*.
You should implement your own module to getting configuration parameters. This can look like:

```
package MyConfig;
use strict; use warnings;
use FindBin;

sub get_data_folder {
    return ($ENV{'DEV_ENVIROMENT'} ?  ## create this variable in your development
        $FindBin::Bin."/../share/somedir/" :
        "/some/other/share/dir/"
    );
}
1;
```

This will allow you to control all your configuration path in one place. But you'll need to change exists code.

Comment: This issue is that I'm installing packages of someone else's Perl scripts. Do you think my only solution is rewriting their scripts to fit my model?

Comment: You can also create a symbolic link from `$InstallFolder/../share/somedir/` to `/some/other/share/dir/` (if your OS supports this). So the real files will be located in folder you need, but scripts will use old path.

Comment: That's a good idea, however won't work in my case. In the case where I update the files in `share` (and change the symlinks to point there) I need to allow the user some way to run the scripts using the old share directory.

Comment: I think, in your custom environment, the simplest way will be to create a custom module.